# Why phpunit doesn't run __destruct() in mocked class and how to force it?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, destructor

Code will explain everything:

```
<?php

class ATest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testDestructorOnOriginalClass() {
        $a = new A();                                             // It
        unset($a);                                                // works
        echo " great!";                                           // great!
        $this->expectOutputString('It works great!');
    }

    public function testDestructorOnMockedClass() {
        $a = $this->getMock('A', array('someNonExistingMethod')); // It
        unset($a);                                                // works
        echo " great!";                                           // great!
        $this->expectOutputString('It works great!');
    }
}

class A {
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "It";
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo " works";
    }
}
```

and the output:

```
# phpunit ATest.php 
PHPUnit 3.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) ATest::testDestructorOnMockedClass
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'It works great!'
+'It great! works'


FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

As you can see in the second test it prints `works` in wrong order, probably because phpunit stores reference to mock somewhere and `__destruct()` is called at the end of test... Ok I've already checked `getMock()` method and indeed it stores reference to mocked object (`$this->mockObjects[] = $mockObject;`) efficiently blocking object from being destructed and so `__destructor()` is never called.

```
/**
 * Returns a mock object for the specified class.
 *
 * @param  string  $originalClassName
 * @param  array   $methods
 * @param  array   $arguments
 * @param  string  $mockClassName
 * @param  boolean $callOriginalConstructor
 * @param  boolean $callOriginalClone
 * @param  boolean $callAutoload
 * @param  boolean $cloneArguments
 * @return PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
 * @throws PHPUnit_Framework_Exception
 * @since  Method available since Release 3.0.0
 */
public function getMock($originalClassName, $methods = array(), array $arguments = array(), $mockClassName = '', $callOriginalConstructor = TRUE, $callOriginalClone = TRUE, $callAutoload = TRUE, $cloneArguments = FALSE)
{
    $mockObject = PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator::getMock(
      $originalClassName,
      $methods,
      $arguments,
      $mockClassName,
      $callOriginalConstructor,
      $callOriginalClone,
      $callAutoload,
      $cloneArguments
    );

    $this->mockObjects[] = $mockObject;

    return $mockObject;
}
```

So the question is - is there a way to prevent this? Ignoring `__destruct()` when it should be called is I think bad limitation.

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or do you really rely on destructor behaviour of dependent classes in your SUT? If so, this might be a sign of bad design. This problem should not really *be* a problem.

Comment: Currently I try to mock PDO class and mimic it's behaviour to end database connection when object is destroyed (and there is no other way to close connection) - so this isn't class I can change (except extending it, and this is what i probably will go for if mocking with `getMock()` won't work).

Comment: Okay, PDO is a special case anyway. If you want to mock it, you *need to* extend it first and override the constructor, otherwise the MockBuilder cannot instantiate it at all (assuming you don't want an actual connection, otherwise you would not mock it, would you?)

Comment: Yeah, exactly, but there is much more in that and too much to explain. I was only curious if I'm missing something with this behavior of `__destruct()` after mocking object. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You're just unsetting the local variable - you are not destroying the object itself.

The object is also kept by PHPUnit itself, too. So there is still a reference around, thus your `unset()` does not lead to a `__destruct()`.

So, the current behavior cannot be changed. Open a bug in the phpunit issue tracker.

Comment: Uhm, this is pointed out in my question, that phpunit keeps reference. I'm asking if this could be avoided so mock will behave exactly like mocked class.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is when you don't pass any values to a second parameter of "`getMock`" method, PHPUnit will stub all methods from the class you are mocking (including "`__destruct`").

But if you specify at least one method (it may be even non existing method) PHPUnit will stub only these methods you pass in second argument.

So if you want keep all methods, but you want also create mock, you should do this in that way:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('A', array('someNonExistingMethod'));
```

If you  change this line you test should pass.

Comment: You gave me a little headache with your simple answer:) because this fixes my provided test case but my real code had this non-empty parameter provided and code still didn't work. The problem with my test case was order in which actions were happening - at the end every object is destroyed, that's way this test case succeeded after your suggestions. Also I couldn't believe that `__destruct()` is invoked even when references exists inside `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::mockObjects[]`. I've updated my question, you will understand what I'm talking about:)

Comment: Ok, I see now what's your point. It seems that PU release mock references just after test is finished.. I can't figured out any way to remove this reference (I though first - maybe there is possible to remove it directly but unfortunately $mockObjects isn't protected but private), sorry. But maybe it's clue that you should be careful with keeping any logic in destructor.

Comment: Sometimes this doesn't depend on you and even if it will then I still think this is a bug in phpunit because it changes behaviour of mocked class when it shouldn't. Currently I'm trying to mimic PDO behaviour which ends connection to database when object is destroyed. It could be hard to change logic of PDO class:) Probably I will end up with extending this class wit custom one and using it as mock instead of the one created by `getMock()`. However it would be nicer if could do this phpunit way.

Answer (score 1):

If we `clone` the mock object and `unset` it, `__destruct()` of the cloned object can be called during the test. It may help you to test `__destruct()`.

Please note that this method cannot prevent `__destruct()` of the original mock object to be called at the end of the test.